# AS400 DB2 Journals search

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I am new to DB2 administration on AS400, could you point me to the best practices/tools to search for errors in the DB2 journals?

So far I use the DSPJRN command but I am unable to make research.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DSPJRN JRN(<LIBRARY>/QSQJRN) FILE(<LIBRARY>/CXPBU00001) RCVRNG(<LIBRARY>/QSQJRN<JOURNAL_NUMBER)                                                                         
5=Display entire entry on a record
F6 Display only entry
F15 Display only entry specific data
From their you can get a job description: <NUMBER>/<USER>/<SYSTEM>
wrkjob <NUMBER>/<USER>/<SYSTEM>
```

And from their option 4 or 10 to see job logs

Answer (score 1):

Can you describe what the "error" is that you are looking for. Journal records my themselves don't really have errors (I think).

I haven't worked on an AS400 for about 10 years, but when I did use it last century I did do some work with Journals looking for the change history of a row over time and found all of the answers I needed in the online manuals.

From memory somehow I think I wrote a export program to save the output of the DSPJRN program and uploaded it into a DB2 Table so that I could query it with SQL.

Comment: The problem is I don't know the error I'm looking for. DB2 is used to persist transactions from an IntegrationServer (WICS 4.4) and the wics logs says something like "Shutting down, see DB2 logs for more details".

Comment: Given you are looking for a generic DB2 error, I suggest looking at the AS/400 system log around the time of the error.  Use the DSPLOG command and prompt it using F4.  You can specify a date and time range on the prompt screen.

Answer (score 1):

The journals can be saved in files aka tables. You can create some programs/SQL to search these tables. On the iSeries one does not have other 'native' tools then the iSeries commands and/or some programming/quering.

I don't know if they are any 'non-native' tools. Remember that DB2/400 is really just one of the many implementations of Universal Database/2. I won't be suprised if a Windows or Linux tools can analyze the iSeries implementation too. They same is true for MQ. A typical iSeries command/menu interface on the iSeries itself (which works fine by the way). Beautifull graphical tools on other platforms that can connect to this iSeries MQ.\

On a second thought, a standard tool for the iSeries is the iSeries navigator. I will check this out on my work tomorrow

Comment: I've checked iSeries Navigator. You can check everything you want to know about the journal administration (think journal, receiver, sequence number and so on). Also, you can see the database transactions. The only thing you can not see is journal entry itself. 

I will think about any tools that I know